# Query to count within intervals in a table

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE pgoals (
gname varchar(100) REFERENCES pplayers(name),
minute integer,
date date,
PRIMARY KEY (gname,minute,date) ) ;
```

The table is obviously filled with a number of goals.

Out of this I want to get a query that shows the number of goals scored within intervals of ten minutes `(1-10, 11-20, 21-30 etc.)`. However, I have no idea how I could do this, except that I should probably use the `COUNT` command.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried group by ?/

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful

Comment: What happens if the goal is scored in the first 59 seconds?, is that minute 0 or minute 1?

Comment: @YashveerSingh Not yet, sadly I have no idea how to use GROUP BY for intervals. I would know how to group be the exact minute, but I would want to group it by intervals of 10 minutes.

Comment: @hacker1337ninja check my answer I hope it is useful

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Some examples are:
Anthony Modeste 61 2016-08-27
Nils Petersen 88 2016-09-10 
Naby Keita 89 2016-09-10

I want the query to show how many goals were scored in specific 10 minutes intervals, the name and date are irrelevant. So in this case it would be 1 goal from 61-70 and 1 goal from 81-90.

Comment: @hacker1337ninja I think if you try my query and play with it you will able to understand group by I put some sample data to play locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table pgoals;

CREATE TABLE pgoals (
gname varchar(100),
minute integer,
date date,
PRIMARY KEY (gname,minute,date) ) ;

insert into pgoals (gname  ,[minute] , [date])values ('A',1,GETDATE())      
         insert into pgoals (gname  ,[minute] , [date])values ('B',3,GETDATE());
         insert into pgoals (gname  ,[minute] , [date])values ('B',4,GETDATE()) ;
         insert into pgoals (gname  ,[minute] , [date])values ('B',5,GETDATE())   ;       
         insert into pgoals (gname  ,[minute] , [date])values ('A',11,GETDATE()) ;        
         insert into pgoals (gname  ,[minute] , [date])values ('A',13,GETDATE());
         insert into pgoals (gname  ,[minute] , [date])values ('B',14,GETDATE());
         insert into pgoals (gname  ,[minute] , [date])values ('B',15,GETDATE());
         insert into pgoals (gname  ,[minute] , [date])values ('A',23,GETDATE());
         insert into pgoals (gname  ,[minute] , [date])values ('A',33,GETDATE());

select date,
       minute/10*10 at,
       count(*)
  from pgoals
 group by date,
       minute/10;

date    at  goals
2017-01-30  0   4
2017-01-30  10  4
2017-01-30  20  1
2017-01-30  30  1
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need, small and elegant:

```
SELECT gname, date, CEILING(minute/10) AS minuteInterval
FROM     pgoals
GROUP BY minuteInterval;
```

Comment: Are we sure the lang is PHP versus SQL Server? Also you forgot to aggregate the ceiling function, but I think this is the right approach

Comment: @scsimon Thanks for point it out to me I forgot that CEILING is for SQL server

Answer (score 2):

Here is a option with a Left Join with an ad-hoc tally table

```
Declare @pgoals  table (gname varchar(100) , minute integer,date date)
Insert Into @pgoals values
 ('aa',4,'2016-01-01')
,('aa',10,'2016-01-01')
,('aa',15,'2016-01-01')
,('aa',25,'2016-01-01')

Select Interval = concat(N-9,' - ',N)
      ,Goals = count(minute)
 From (Select Top 10  N=10*Row_Number() Over (Order By Number) From master..spt_values ) A
 Left Join @pgoals B
   on minute between N-9 and N
 Group By N
```

Returns

```
Interval    Goals
1 - 10      2
11 - 20     1
21 - 30     1
31 - 40     0
41 - 50     0
51 - 60     0
61 - 70     0
71 - 80     0
81 - 90     0
91 - 100    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the current information I came up with this please have a look if it is helpful

```
    declare  @goal as table (Id int ,name nvarchar(5) , [minute] int, [date] datetime )


         insert into @goal (Id ,name  ,[minute] , [date])values (1,'A',1,GETDATE())      
         insert into @goal (Id ,name  ,[minute] , [date])values (1,'B',3,GETDATE())
         insert into @goal (Id ,name  ,[minute] , [date])values (1,'B',4,GETDATE()) 
         insert into @goal (Id ,name  ,[minute] , [date])values (1,'B',5,GETDATE())          
         insert into @goal (Id ,name  ,[minute] , [date])values (1,'A',11,GETDATE())         
         insert into @goal (Id ,name  ,[minute] , [date])values (1,'A',13,GETDATE())
         insert into @goal (Id ,name  ,[minute] , [date])values (1,'B',14,GETDATE())
         insert into @goal (Id ,name  ,[minute] , [date])values (1,'B',15,GETDATE())
         insert into @goal (Id ,name  ,[minute] , [date])values (1,'A',23,GETDATE())
         insert into @goal (Id ,name  ,[minute] , [date])values (1,'A',33,GETDATE())



         select count(*)as goals,name,
        case when ([minute]/10) = 0 then 10 else (minute/10)*10 end as mints,

         date from @goal group by minute,name,date
```

Answer (score 1):

rextester link: http://rextester.com/MSW83979

```
create table pgoals (
    gname varchar(100)
  , minute integer
  , date date
  , PRIMARY KEY (gname,minute,date) 
);
insert into pgoals values
 ('a',1,'20170130')
,('a',9,'20170130')
,('a',12,'20170130')
,('a',14,'20170130')
,('a',34,'20170130')
,('a',54,'20170130');
```

query

```
with m as (
  select nf, nt 
    from (values (1,10),(11,20),(21,30),(31,40),(41,50),(51,60)) t(nf, nt)
)
select 
    [interval] ='('+convert(varchar(3),m.nf)+ '-' +convert(varchar(3),m.nt)+')'
  , goals      = count(g.minute)
  from m
    left join pgoals g on g.minute between m.nf and m.nt
  group by m.nf, m.nt
  order by m.nf
```

results:

```
+----------+-------+
| interval | goals |
+----------+-------+
| (1-10)   |     2 |
| (11-20)  |     2 |
| (21-30)  |     0 |
| (31-40)  |     1 |
| (41-50)  |     0 |
| (51-60)  |     1 |
+----------+-------+
```